# Dubious proposition at best - meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

The sentence I'm wondering about is:
`His approval would be a dubious proposition at best`

The meaning I've realized about this one is something like this:

Some guy would not approve something, and actually totally does not agree or against of the dialog's context.

Could you provide some similar examples with the word `at best`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Dubious*" means *questionable*, or *suspicious* - something that you do not trust.

"*At best*" is an idiomatic way of saying that what you are describing is the best-case-scenario or the nicest thing you could possibly say about something. The implication is that if the "best" thing you can say is bad, the reality is that it could be even worse.

So "a dubious proposition at best" means that the proposition is *definitely* questionable, but *probably* a lot worse.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples in to your post. Really do appreciate it